# Snowflake - how to refer to internal stage for specified table with special characters in its name?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake allows table names to contain special characters, as long as the table name is surrounded by double quotes.

However, I'm having trouble referring to the internal stage for such tables. Double quotes don't seem to work when referring to these stages.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE "cars (sedan)" (myint int)
```

Attempts to refer the internal stage for this table will fail (this was done on snowflake's online console):

```
LIST @%"cars (sedan)"
```

or

```
PUT file:///tmp/myfile.csv @%"cars (sedan)"
```

error message (for LIST):

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 13 unexpected '('.
```

If the table name was something nice (like "cars"), then the query will succeed.

What is the proper way to refer to these stages?

Comment: Something seems to be off about how LIST uses table literals. I tried just about every way to handle literals and got various less than helpful errors. See options here: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/literals-table.html

sidenote: I'd recommend not using such odd characters in table names.

Comment: Agreed with David - don't (for the love of all good things, like ice cream, and puppies, and getting sleep, and rainbows, and snowflakes) create a table with such a name.   CREATE TABLE cars_sedan .....  <<< much better!

Comment: no, yes I agree, those are horrible table names, and anyone using them is just asking trouble for themselves.
However, I'm asking in a more general sense, since it seems that Snowflake wants to support these horrible table names, surely there must be a way to refer to them when working with their internal stages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping it in single quotes:

```
list '@%"cars (sedan)"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you may also use $$ for enclosing the identifier and @%, as below:

```
ls $$@%"cars (sedan)"$$;
```

Comment: this also works! I'd choose this as an accepted answer as well if I could choose 2 answers. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation, when copying data from files in a table stage, the FROM clause can be omitted because Snowflake automatically checks for files in the table stage.

Could you omit the FROM since the name is throwing the error?

Comment: That would work if the OP was trying to COPY INTO that table, but the request was for the syntax of the LIST function.

Comment: that's great, one less thing to worry about when using COPY INTO.
However, how would one upload data to the table's internal stage using PUT, since it would also require the table's stage name?